# Exclude a file on an Apache server from SSL, when the server is protected with a perm redirect?

Tags: ssl, redirect, apache2

I have an apache 2 web server running on Ubuntu Server.  I have the entire server redirecting to SSL with the following site enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hda.surfrock66.com/
    Redirect permanent / https://hda.surfrock66.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a single little obnoxious php file which enables a data upload from an app which cannot validate SSL.  Is there a way to disable ssl for a single file on a single site, maybe with .htaccess or something?  I've read extensive articles on the matter, and none of them have worked, so I'm stuck asking for help from scratch.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the problem rather than applying a workaround? e.g. with an instance of stunnel or stud near to the broken application.

Comment: The application is an android app which I do not control; this bug has been filed with the app author for over a year but there has been no response on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use a `RewriteCond` with mod_rewrite to exclude that particular path from the redirection. I'm doing this all the time to support Let's Encrypt ACME requests over HTTP but redirect everything else to HTTPS (and have the HTTPS vhost announce HSTS for clients' benefit).

I fail to understand your use case, however. The PHP script really *shouldn't* care about the transport.

Try something like this in your `<VirtualHost>` container instead of that `Redirect` stanza:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded/url.php$
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [last,redirect=301]
```

This will redirect (using a 301 *Moved Permanently* response code) everything *except* `/excluded/url.php` to the corresponding location on the same host name over HTTPS. Using `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of an explicit host name means the same configuration snippet can be used in any virtual host container (I have mine in a separate snippet file that I `Include` in a number of vhosts, massively cutting down on repetition in the configuration files).

Yes, it's a little more complicated, but it's also far more versatile. Note that the argument to `RewriteCond` is a regular expression; prefixed here by `!` because we are inverting the meaning of it. (The condition for the RewriteRule to be applied is that the RewriteCond *does not* match, thus excluding that one location.)

Also, make sure that you have a `DocumentRoot` in the `<VirtualHost>` container that points to the correct location in your file system. Otherwise, the redirection may work as desired, but the file won't necessarily be found (depending on other configuration values).

[mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)

Comment: So this sounds really close to the answer, but I'm still having trouble.  The actual URL I need: [link](http://hda.surfrock66.com/torquetest/upload_data.php) still won't work.  It no longer redirects, but the actual page just gets me a 404.

VHost line: "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/torquetest/upload_data.php$"

The android app torque uses this to upload ODBII data to this self-hosted server, but the app can't negotiate SSL certs even if they're valid, so it has to fall back to http.

Comment: @surfrock66 Well, the obvious question then becomes: Have you verified *for a fact* that the file exists *where Apache is looking?* The second half is important; I don't see any `DocumentRoot` in the `<VirtualHost>` container that you included in your question. Try adding one (even *if* it has the same value as the global one), and let us know if it works any better then. Also check for any aliases, `<Location>`, `<Directory>` or other possibly relevant configuration directives. If all else fails, you could try setting up a brand new, absolutely bare-bones Apache instance on a different IP.

Comment: @surfrock66 Glad I was able to help.